# How to show a specific keyword in an article randomly

Tags: php

I have a keyword "Keyword1" and I have an article with "keyword1" appearing several times in it. Each of the "Keyword1" in the article is a link leading to different websites.
So I am trying to randomly show one "keyword1" everytime I refresh the page.

So far I have tried this using stripos() like this.

```
$needle = "keyword1";
$haystack = 'this is an article with [keyword1] appearing seral times with different links. [Keyword1] blahblah [keyword1]' ;

if(stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false){


$links = $haystack;
$links_to_array = explode(" ", $links);
$randomize = array_rand($links_to_array, 1);
echo ($links_to_array[$randomize]);
}
```

SO when I do this... it does not pick one of the keyword1, it also shows a word in the article randomly. You can copy the code and try it for yourself by refreshing your page.

I only want a random keyword1 to be shown.

How can I do this?

Comment: How is `keyword1` random if you want to pick it every time?

Comment: It is a hyperlink leading to different locations.

Comment: Then why don't you post a relevant `$haystack`, with hyperlinks?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. Where are the links that you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are about to do. But the following code may help. I'm using the function [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php) to find all occurences of keyword1 - case insensitive: `/i`

```
<?php

$needle = "keyword1";
$haystack = 'this is an article with [keyword1] appearing seral times with different links. [Keyword1] blahblah [keyword1]' ;

if(stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false){
    preg_match_all('/\[keyword1\]/i', $haystack, $matches);
    $links_to_array = $matches[0];
    $randomize = array_rand($links_to_array, 1);
    echo ($links_to_array[$randomize]);
}
```